# QByteArray to QString to std::stringstream doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, stringstream, qstring

anyone know why

```
QString Lulu ( data ); //data is a QByteArry ( from a QNetworkrequest ) 
std::stringstream streamedJson ;

   // QString Lulu ( data.data() );
    qDebug()<< "Lulu:" << Lulu; // here it views the right string

    streamedJson << Lulu.toStdString();
    qDebug() << "streamedJson: "<< streamedJson ; // here it views 0x7fffc9d46568
```

doesn't works ? 
why it dont view the String here ? 
finally i would parse it and give the parsed string out

```
boost::property_tree::ptree propertyTree;
            try
            {
                boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(streamedJson, propertyTree);
            }
catch(boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error& ex)
       {
           qDebug() << "ex: "<< ex.what(); // this and Lulu views the same (unparsed) string 
           qDebug ("propertyree error");
       }
```

at the moment it only views "propertyree error". but it should print the parsed String in my console

Comment: Inside the `catch` block, try `qDebug() << ex.what();` and see why it failed.

Comment: Yes, in ex.what() and lulu are the same strings. But the ex string should be parsed , or ? why this isn't parsed ?

Comment: Because `boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json` cannot parse the data string in `Lulu`. Your program is correct, however the input data is wrong, maybe not a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

`std::stringstream` cannot be directly used with `QDebug::operator<<`. You can explicitly convert it to `QString`. For example,

```
qDebug() << "streamedJson: " << QString::fromStdString(streamedJson.str());
```

The `streamedJson.str()` returns an `std::string`, and then converted to `QString` using `QString::fromStdString`.

Your program prints `0x7fffc9d46568` probably because the `streamedJson` is converted to a `qDebug`-printable object implicitly. Or maybe there is an `operator<<` function somewhere in your program that takes `std::stringstream` as input.

Comment: Okey, but finally i would parse it and give out  the parsed strings
this QDebugs are only for me for help.  boost::property_tree::ptree propertyTree;
            try
            {
                boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(streamedJson, propertyTree);
            } what i should do now with my streamedJson ?

Comment: thats have a bad format, i add it in my question examplecode.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialization of the `QString` variable as explained below and try putting the value into a `std::string` variable before pushing it into the `std::stringstream`.

```
QString Lulu = QString(data);
std::stringstream streamedJson ;
std::string strLulu = Lulu.toStdString();
streamedJson << strLulu;
qDebug() << "streamedJson: "<< streamedJson;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you , but so its the same like before. it views 0x7fffa61bc289

Answer (score -1):

Class `QString` has function `std::string   toStdString() const`. Maybe you should use it this way:

```
streamedJson << Lulu.toStdString();
```

If it will not work you can try

```
streamedJson << Lulu.toStdString().c_str();
```

If it will not work too we would find another possible solution. Good luck!

**EDIT:**
I've read several documents and I guess I've solved your problem. Class `std::stringstream` has inner representation of string. In order to get `std::string` from this class you should use its function `str()`:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/
Then your code should be looking like this:

```
string myString = streamedJson.str();
std::cout << myString;
```

I believe it will work.

Comment: Thank you. streamedJson << Lulu.toStdString().c_str(); an streamedJson << Lulu.toStdString(); doesn't works, i have copy the false code in the example ;) now its the right.

Comment: Do you have an other idea :( ?

Comment: You can change your code in order to test, how it works. I would create an additional string, which will contain the value returned from toStdString(). Add a breakpoint at the beginning and trace your program.

Comment: i have debugg my  programm .. see the comments in my bsp code. In Lulu it views the right , but in streamedJson its have the false string .. before the strings is right ..